# All linear maps are differentiable?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

**Question:** 
I wonder all linear maps $y \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ are of the form $y(t) = ct$ for some constant $c$ or not (without assuming continuous nor differentiable).

**My attempt:** Let $y$ be a linear map. Then
$y(\lambda t) = \lambda y(t).$
In addition, assume $y$ is also *differentiable*. Put $x = \lambda t$ and differentiate the above with respect to the parameter $\lambda$,
$$\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}(x) \cdot \frac{\partial x}{\partial \lambda}(t) = y(t) = \frac{1}{\lambda} y(\lambda t) = \frac{1}{\lambda}y(x).$$
From here, we get ODE
$$y(x) = x \frac{dy}{dx}(x).$$
I solve this by separation of variables and get solutions
$y(x) = cx$
for some *positive* constant $c$. So, contrary to my expectation, we get solutions
$$y(t) = ct \qquad (c > 0).$$

**Needed help:**

1. Why the coefficient $c$ is positive? Do I make a mistake? [Solved. Thank you muzzlator!]
2. If a linear map is differentiable then it is of the form $y(t) = ct$ as shown above. Is it true that all linear maps are differentiable? I tried but I got lost:
   $$ \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}\frac{y(t + \varepsilon) - y(t)}{\varepsilon} = \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}\frac{y(\varepsilon)}{\varepsilon}.$$
   So I suspect it is false, but such a example doesn't occur to me. Would you give me such a example? Or I completely go wrong way?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "linear". If you only require that
$$y(ct)=c\cdot y(t)$$
for *rational* numbers $c$, then there are lots more linear functions. [See this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation).

Comment: @ZevChonoles: What I mean by saying "linear" is
$$f(a x + b y) = a f(x) + b f(y),$$
though I only use $f(ax) = af(x)$ in the question.

Comment: The issue is, what are you using the letters $a$ and $b$ to represent? Can they be any real numbers?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any $t\in\mathbb{R}$ you can write $y(t)=y(t\cdot1)=t\cdot y(1)=c\cdot t$, where $c=y(1)$ which is a constant.

Comment: Thank you! It seems that I think the problem too difficulty.

Comment: is any linear map $T$ : $\mathbb{R^n}$ $\rightarrow$ $\mathbb{R^m}$ differentiable?

Answer (score 1):

All $\mathbb{R}$-linear maps from $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are of the form $f(x) = c x$.  See @Zev's comment for the rationale.

How did you get the constant being positive when solving the ODE? You should end up getting a generic constant.  Remember that the integral of $\frac{1}{x}$ is $\ln |x| + C$ and not just $\ln x$ + C.

Comment: No, all $\mathbb{R}$-linear maps ***are*** of the form $f(x)=cx$. It's when you only require additivity, or equivalently $\mathbb{Q}$-linearity, that more examples appear.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry.  I'll remove it.

Comment: @muzzlator: Thank you! The last sentence shows me exactly what I go wrong.